# Python - Simple way to do parallel delayed subprocess and not wait

Tags: python, parallel-processing, subprocess, delay

I am new in programming and I have a python script that checks the database and then activates  some relays for a period of time . I put the sleep time in the code below , but the problem is that the program waits for every delay and when I am pressing one button after another, the second relay waits for the first one to finish. Is there any way to start a parallel process that just switches on and off the relay and then terminates itself ? I had a look to the subprocesses but to be honest I don't understand very well how to use it and I couldn't find a simple example that tells you how to start a simple function in parallel.

```
while True:
    cursor.execute("""SELECT pinNumber, delayTime FROM expanders WHERE request = 1""")
    row = cursor.fetchall ()
    resetRequest = 0
    for r in row:
        pinNumber = int(r[0])
        delayTime = int(r[1])
        voltage = 0
        newVoltage = 1
        wiringpi.digitalWrite(pinNumber, newVoltage)
        print ('Relay %s = %s' % (pinNumber, newVoltage))
        sleep (delayTime)
        wiringpi.digitalWrite(pinNumber, voltage)
        print ('Relay %s = %s' % (pinNumber,voltage))
    sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) package.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print('hello ', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    # do something here
    p.join()
```